# Where to download the binaries of the latese version of System.Data.SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

newbie here, sorry if this is an obvious question.

I have never used SQLite before. According to [this page](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/), the latest version of System.Data.SQLite should be downloaded from http://system.data.sqlite.org/.

But I couldn't find a download link. Should I download the source code then compile it on my local machine? If so, could you please tell me where to download the source code? Sorry, I have no idea what "Branches", "Leaves", "trunks" mean.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link instead: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

The new http://system.data.sqlite.org/ site is the integrated web-server of a Fossil repository. Therefore it exposes SCM functionality like branches in its web-interface. You may take a look at fossil at: http://www.fossil-scm.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay! But I can only find version 1.0.66.0 (Apr 18, 2010) on this site. According to [this page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki), the latest version is 1.0.68.0 (February 2011).

Comment: Does not look to good according to this post: http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/2948/10534.aspx#10534

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue. You can get the source code from [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/zip/System.Data.SQLite-26379a6c73bcd60b.zip?uuid=26379a6c73bcd60bebd89502df57637b586f8eeb). It builds fine for me in VS2010.

Comment: Thanks for the link! But its readme file said "_Version 1.0.67.0 January 3, 2011... Released to the public domain, use at your own risk!... The latest version can be downloaded [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2)_". So it seems the latest (stable) version is still 1.0.66.0.

Answer (score 0):

The latest System.data.sqlite binaries are available at
  http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki

It has instructions/info and the latest binary versions for the variations of .Net and Visual Studio.